# Grails Search Controller

Tags: search, grails

i have three class Course, Consultant and WorkPlacement.
I want to create a search box from where i can search the fields of course, consultant and workPlacement class.

Comment: this questions has already been answered with 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200040/complex-search-across-grails-domain-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the searchable plugin [here](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable).  It's built for things like this and should get you lots of powerful functionality with little effort.